# Sorting sets based on the order of a string?

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort a set of character sets so that they are in the same order as a string. So take this input

```
"ADFE"    [(FE, 3), (A, 5), (D, 6)]
```

The output would be:

```
"A D FE"    [(A, 5), (D, 6), (FE, 3)]
```

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: what code have you written?

Comment: Also, I edited the question, but it was based on how _I_ understood the question... feel free to suggest an edit if it's not what you wanted...

Comment: @erip imagine that the latin character were replaced with korean characters, or any non-latin characters

Comment: What are `FE`, `A`, and `D` supposed to be? Are they variables holding some other value? Should they actually be strings, i.e. `'FE'`, `'A'`, and `'D'`?

Comment: @barny my solution is currently woven into another algorithm, and rather than implement the solution into the original code I'm going to post processes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a string such as `'ADFE'` and you have a list such as `[('FE', 3), ('A', 5), ('D', 6)]`.  You then want to sort that list based on the string.  To do that, you can use `sorted()` with a key:

```
letters = 'ADFE'
old = [('FE', 3), ('A', 5), ('D', 6)]
new = sorted(old, key=lambda x: letters.index(x[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
order = 'A D FE'.split(' ')
unordered_list = [['FE', 3], ['A', 5], ['D', 6]]
ordered_list = sorted(unordered_list, key=lambda x: order.index(x[0]))
```

Comment: As I understand the question, the input string is "ADFE", not "A D FE". But you can do the same using `index` on the string itself. Also have to do `order.index(x[0])`

Comment: @AmiTavory Well, the question as far as I see is about sorting lists and not about about spliting strings, but ok

Comment: @Mr.E Since you see it differently (and it's perhaps subjective), I removed the downvote.